# remove previous JSON Data in client side and reload new Data on button click

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, json

in page load i am getting json data that`s ok but i want when i click on search button it will reload a new JSON Data according to Searching Criteria and remove previous JSON Data from client side.

in Search Criteria there are some dropdownlist and textboxes with Search button and all the controls in Search Criteria are Server Controls (Asp.net)

My problem is that when i click on search button it is generating a new JSON Data with Old JSON Data which i really don`t want for example in page load there is Apple but when i select Orange from DropDownlist and hit on search button it will showing both Apple and Orange, it should be only showing Orange as i was searching for only Orange not for both apple and orange..

**here is my code for displaying the json Data**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        function StockList() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "stocklist.aspx/Select_Search",
                data: "{}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(data) {
                    var j = 1;
                    var count = 9;

                    for (var i = 0; i < data.d.length; i++) {


                        var output = '<ul class="selection page-' + (i == count || (i && !(i % 9)) ? j++ : j) + '">';
                        output += '<li >';
                        output += '<table><tr>';
                        output += '<td><img src="http://localhost:37245/NewPeaceAuto - Steer_Well/WebStock_Images/' + data.d[i].Image1 + '" alt=""/></td>';
                        output += '<td>CHASSIS NO:</td><td>' + data.d[i].CHASSIS_NO + '</td>';
                        output += '<td>MODEL:</td><td>' + data.d[i].MODEL + '</td>';
                        output += '<td>COLOR:</td><td>' + data.d[i].color + '</td>';
                        output += '<td>TRANS:</td><td>' + data.d[i].TRANSMISSION + '</td>';
                        output += '<td>DOOR:</td><td>' + data.d[i].DOOR + '</td>';
                        output += '<td>MAKE:</td><td>' + data.d[i].MAKE + '</td>';
                        output += '</tr></table></li></ul>';
                        $("#update").append(output);
                        count = count + 9;
                    }


                }
            });
        }
</script>
```

**on page Load**

```
<body onload="StockList();">
```

**on page load or button click JSON Data is appending inside #update id div**

```
<div id="update"></div>
```

**on button click from Search Criteria by selecting a value from dropdownlist**

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlMake" runat="server" DataSourceID="odsMake" 
        DataTextField="make" DataValueField="makeID">
 </asp:DropDownList>

<asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClientClick="StockList(); return false;"/>
```

Comment: What kind of control is 'update'?  Why don't you clear it before filling it with more stuff?

Comment: hi @SteveWellens it`s updating the #update ID with more stuff.. that`s my question how to clear #update ID before filling the more stuff?

Comment: @SteveWellens update id is just a simple div i have updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the following change .I think it may help you:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        function StockList() {
           var output; //declare the variable
           $("#update").append(output); // append a null to div
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "stocklist.aspx/Select_Search",
                data: "{}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(data) {
                    var j = 1;
                    var count = 9;

                    for (var i = 0; i < data.d.length; i++) {


                        output = '<ul class="selection page-' + (i == count || (i && !(i % 9)) ? j++ : j) + '">';
                        output += '<li >';
                        output += '<table><tr>';
                        output += '<td><img src="http://localhost:37245/NewPeaceAuto - Steer_Well/WebStock_Images/' + data.d[i].Image1 + '" alt=""/></td>';
                        output += '<td>CHASSIS NO:</td><td>' + data.d[i].CHASSIS_NO + '</td>';
                        output += '<td>MODEL:</td><td>' + data.d[i].MODEL + '</td>';
                        output += '<td>COLOR:</td><td>' + data.d[i].color + '</td>';
                        output += '<td>TRANS:</td><td>' + data.d[i].TRANSMISSION + '</td>';
                        output += '<td>DOOR:</td><td>' + data.d[i].DOOR + '</td>';
                        output += '<td>MAKE:</td><td>' + data.d[i].MAKE + '</td>';
                        output += '</tr></table></li></ul>';
                        $("#update").append(output);
                        count = count + 9;
                    }
                     output=""; //make the output to null

                }
            });
        }
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Just put `$("#update").empty()` in code either before AJAX  request or in success callback before start compiling new html

Comment: hi @charlietfl i have tried this and also this $('#update').html(''); but it`s not working

Comment: update code in questions showing where you put it. Has to work if put in right place

Comment: i put it before Ajax request like this $("#update").empty() $.ajax({}) and also tried before string new html like this 

success: function(data) {
                    $("#update").empty();

Comment: doesn't make sense that it doesn't work...create a demo that replicates problem

Comment: Try this: alert($("#update").length) to make sure you are actually getting the update element.  It should display a 1.